# Не работает Видеоплеер Iphone

Tags: iphone, видео, safari

Перестал работать встроенный(по умолчанию) видеоплеер в iphone(на ютубе все норм)
Включаю видео в сафари 
Звук идет (изображения нету)
С чем связано?

Comment: а видео, которые Вы снимали на телефон, работают?

Comment: Да все работает.
Именно в safari ,частично в вк(где плеер стоит с возможностью перемота на 15с)

Comment: окэ. Вы пробовали на других сайтах через *Safari* просматривать видео?

Comment: Да на разных пробовал,везде где включается этот видеоплеер(15 сек перемотка) видео не работает,звук идет.
Например в Телеге свой плеер,там все гуд

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена так:
Был сломан аудиокодек , после починки все заработало